# Facing error: TypeError: cannot create mpf from [0.055,

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I am trying to do curve fitting using scipy curve fit. Also I require mpmath and numpy.

```
import mpmath as mpm
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
import scipy.optimize as opt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import csv
x = pd.read_csv('pyex.csv')
n = len(x['Time (sec)'])
T = 303.15
R = 0.082 
P0 = 17.18
def function(c,t):
    A11 = 1.0+mpm.exp(np.array(((-t/c[0])+c[1])).tolist())
    A22 = c[2]*np.exp(-c[3]/(R*T))
    A33 = (P0/c[4])-1
    AA = np.abs(mpm.polylog(2,A11))
    b11 = (1/(1-A11))**2
    b22 = mpm.log(np.array(A11**2).tolist())
    B1 = mpm.log(np.array(b11).tolist())+b22
    C11 = A11/(A11-1)
    C = mpm.log(mpm.exp(np.array(c[1]).tolist())*C11)
    Z = c[0]*(AA+0.5*(B1-C)*C)
    D = 1+np.exp(c[1])
    E = np.abs(mpm.polylog(2,D))
    G = np.log(np.exp(-2*c[1]))
    H = np.log(D**2)-np.log(D)
    const = -c[0]*(E+0.5*(G+H)*np.log(D))
    I = Z+const
    return 1-2.71**(A22*A33*I)
c = [255.00,0.055,0.01,0.007,16.63]
y = np.empty(n)
for i in range(n):
    y[i] = function(c,x['Time (sec)'][i])
plt.plot(x['Time (sec)'],x['F (exp)'], 'o'),plt.plot(x['Time (sec)'],y,'r')
plt.show()
t1 = x['Time (sec)'].values
t = np.array(t1).flatten()
hr1 = x['F (exp)'].values
hr = np.array(hr1).flatten()
c,cov = curve_fit(function(c,x['Time (sec)']),t,hr,c)
print(c)
for i in range(n):
    y[i] = function(x['Time (sec)'][i],c[0],c[1],c[2],c[3],c[4])
```

So I am getting error

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Downloads\test2.py", line 42, in <module>
    c,cov = curve_fit(function(c,x['Time (sec)']),t,hr,c)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Downloads\test2.py", line 15, in function
    A11 = 1.0+mpm.exp(np.array(((-t/c[0])+c[1])).tolist())
  File "C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\envs\surajit\lib\site-packages\mpmath\ctx_mp_python.py", line 989, in f
    x = ctx.convert(x)
  File "C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\envs\surajit\lib\site-packages\mpmath\ctx_mp_python.py", line 669, in convert
    return ctx._convert_fallback(x, strings)
  File "C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\envs\surajit\lib\site-packages\mpmath\ctx_mp.py", line 634, in _convert_fallback
    raise TypeError("cannot create mpf from " + repr(x))
TypeError: cannot create mpf from [0.055,"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems like this is something that could be solved with debugging.
Apparently, `mpm.exp()` doesn't accept the array that you pass it.

Try to split this line:

```
A11 = 1.0+mpm.exp(np.array(((-t/c[0])+c[1])).tolist())
```

Into this:

```
x = np.array(((-t/c[0])+c[1])).tolist()
A11 = 1.0 + mpm.exp(x)
```

Now, try to stop on the second line by setting a breakpoint or by adding `print(x)` to your code.

Then try to understand what's wrong with your array.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried with your suggestion. However, the error is still not resolved (TypeError: cannot create mpf from array([). The error is from the polylog function which is using mpmath for the calculation. When I removed the polylog/mpmath then the code is running. However, I need the polylog function. Please suggest a solution.